# Binding Error ORA-01006 & table error ORA-00903 in VB.Net 2015 while using variables with query

Tags: vb.net, oracle11gr2

Inserting into a table works fine with this

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into ATTENDANCE(EMP_ID,T_DATE,ATTENDANCE,TL_ID) Values(:var1,TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy'),:var3 ,:var4)"
```

but when i want to concatenate a textbox value/variable with the query it gives binding error

> ORA-01006 You tried to issue a bind call for a variable that was not listed in the corresponding SQL statement.

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into " & text1.Text & "(T_DATE,ATTENDANCE,TL_ID) Values(TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy'), :var3 ,:var4)"
```

or`"cmd.CommandText = "Insert into :text(T_DATE,ATTENDANCE,TL_ID) Values(TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy'), :var3 ,:var4)"`

the :text part being `cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("text", text1.Text))`

which gives another error

> ORA-00903  You tried to execute a SQL statement that included an invalid table name or the table name does not exist.

even though the table is present/exists.

Comment: I don't know enough about queries, but what is the value of Text1.Text?

Comment: a49 ,its a table i have created

Comment: Forgive my continuing ignorance, but would `a49(EMP_ID,T_DATE,ATTENDANCE,TL_ID)` be valid code? According to your 2nd sample code the first occurence of "ATTENDANCE" would be re placed by "a49"

Comment: but my code should look like this right ------   Insert into a49(T_DATE,ATTENDANCE,TL_ID) Values(TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy'), :var3 ,:var4) .................And the a49 table does work as it qualifies for a table_name in oracle 11g

Comment: As i was saying, I know almost nothing about queries and was just trying to be a bit helpful and rule out some things :-)

Comment: I notic also that in your working code sample, the part `Values(:var1,TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy'),:var3 ,:var4)"` contains `:var1`, but in the non working sample `:var1` is missing. I don't know if this is significant or not. Either way - I hope that someone with more knowledge of queries manages to help you find a solution :)

Comment: What are ORA-00903 and ORA-01006?  Please provide the text of those Oracle errors.  Most people probably don't know the error numbers from memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into '" & text1.Text & "'(T_DATE,ATTENDANCE,TL_ID) Values(TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy'), :var3 ,:var4)"
```

or

`dim str as String = "Insert into '" & text1.Text & "'(T_DATE,ATTENDANCE,TL_ID) Values(TO_DATE(sysdate, 'dd-MON-yy'), :var3 ,:var4)"`

**cmd.CommandText = str**